# rails postgres ERROR: invalid input syntax for type double precision

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

i'm trying the following:

```
user_calendars.where("extract(day from time_from) = ? ", next_day)
```

But i keep getting this Error:

```
PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type double precision: "Saturday" LINE 1: ..."user_id" = $1 AND (extract(day from time_from) = 'Saturday'...
```

Not sure why it points out type double.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In PostgreSQL, the expression `extract(day from time_from)` returns a number of type double, representing the day of the month. *Saturday* is clearly not a valid double.

If you need the argument to `where()` to match the string 'Saturday' (to match the day of the week), then use the `to_char()` function.

```
user_calendars.where("trim(to_char(time_from, 'Day')) = ? ", next_day)
```

You need `trim()`, because this kind of call to `to_char()` is padded to 9 characters.

Case is significant for the argument 'Day'. If you key it as 'day', the returned value won't match 'Saturday'.  Instead, an expression like `to_char(time_from, 'day')` will return something like 'saturday'.

Comment: Or convert the Ruby `next_day` string to a number that matches what `extract(day ...)` returns.