# Returning a list of posts based on the month they were created at

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Rails newbie here.

I'm writing a blog in Rails 4.2 and I'd like to have links in a side navigation bar to filter the results based on the month in which the post was created. I have the list of months displaying correctly, but I can't display a new index page with the correctly filtered posts.

When the user clicks on the month in the side navigation I want to send that month in the params hash and then have an if/else clause for filtering the results. The problem is that I have applied the strftime("%B") method in the view (so that the month is more readable) before passing it to the params hash, but I can't apply it to the where clause within the controller.

In the controller I'm looking for something like:

```
def index
  if params[:month]
    @posts = (:created_at.strftime("%B") => params[:month])
  else 
    @posts = Post.all
 end
```

But I get the error message: undefined method `strftime' for :created_at:Symbol

The code in my view is:

```
<h4>By month </h4>
   <% @posts.group_by{|post| post.created_at.strftime("%B")}.each do |month, values| %>
      <%= link_to month, posts_path(:month => month) %>
   <% end %>
```

I've managed to get something similar working with the category of the post, but this is because I haven't run any methods on it before I send it in the params hash.

Working code in the controller:

```
def index
   if params[:category]
    @posts = Post.where(:category => params[:category]).order(created_at: :desc)
   else
    @posts = Post.all
  end
end
```

Working code in the view:

```
<h4>By category</h4>
  <% @posts.group_by{|post| post.category}.each do |category, value| %>
    <%= link_to category, posts_path(:category => category) %>
  <% end %>
```

I'd appreciate any ideas as to how I can get this to work. Thanks in advance.

***UPDATE***
Managed to get this working in the end using the following code in the index action in the controller:

```
@posts = Post.where("trim(to_char(created_at, 'month')) = ?", params[:month].downcase)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following query to get posts by month:

```
Post.where("extract(month from created_at) = ?", params[:month])
```

I tried this with Postgres database. Not sure this will work with Mysql. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks madyrockss, this didn't work for me but sent me in the right direction towards this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27203981/5097668

Answer (score 0):

maybe worth trying https://github.com/radar/by_star

With that gem you can go `Post.by_month(params[:month])`

Answer (score 0):

You could define a `scope` for that in your model:

```
scope :by_month, lambda { |date| where(:created_at => date.beginning_of_month..date.end_of_month).order(:created_at) }
```

This allows you to do this in your controllers list action:

```
selected_month = Time.parse(params[:month]) rescue Time.now
@posts = Post.by_month(selected_month)
```

To generate links for every unique months `post`s have been written in. you can `map` the posts and generate links with `params[:month]` for all unique months:

```
<% @posts.only(:created_at).map {|p| p.created_at.beginning_of_month}.uniq.sort.each do |m| %>
  <%= link_to m.strftime("%B"), :month => m %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: this will catch THIS years month, not last years months